# Angular 2 How do I edit an element name?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, storage

I'm already confused ... I want to create the ability to edit the name of an element by clicking on the button. All elements are stored in Storage. How it can be done in my case.

file home.html

```
<ion-list>

<ion-item *ngFor="let place of places ; let i  = index" (click)="onOpenPlace(place)">
  <p class="list_geo"> {{ place.title }}</p>
  <ion-buttons end>
  <button ion-button color="danger" (click)="deletePlace(i)">Delete</button>

  <!-- ************* EDIT ****** does not work ************* -->
  <button ion-button class="button button-positive" (click)="showEditModalPlace(i)"><ion-icon name="create"></ion-
    icon>_Edit</button>
  <!-- ************* EDIT ****** does not work ************* -->

 </ion-buttons> 
</ion-item>
```

file home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

import { ModalController, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { NewPlacePage } from "../new-place/new-place";
import { PlacePage } from "../place/place";
import { PlacesService } from "../../services/places.service";
import { Place } from "../../model/place.model";
import { EditPlacePage } from '../edit-place/edit-place';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
 // places: {title: string}[] = [];
  private places: Place[] = [];

  constructor(
    private storage: Storage,
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    private placesService: PlacesService,
    private modalCtrl: ModalController) {

  }

  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.placesService.getPlaces()
      .then(
        (places) => this.places = places
      );
  }

 <!-- ************* EDIT ****** does not work ************* -->

                  // Modal window EditPlacePage

showEditModalPlace(i) {
    console.log(i);
    this.modalCtrl.create(EditPlacePage).present();
  }
 <!-- ************* EDIT ****** does not work ************* -->

}
```

file edit-place.html

```
<form (submit)="UpdatePlace(f.value)" #f="ngForm">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Edit</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" name="activetitle" [(ngModel)]="activetitle" required (change)="placeChange(i)"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <button ion-button block type="submit" [disabled]="!f.valid">Edit Place</button>
  </form>
```

file edit-place.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';
  import { Place } from "../../model/place.model";
  import { PlacesService } from "../../services/places.service";
  import { Router, ActivatedRouter, Params} from '@angular/router';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-edit-place',
  templateUrl: 'edit-place.html',
})
export class EditPlacePage {
    private places: Place[] = [];
        activetitle: string;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private viewCtrl: ViewController, private placesService: PlacesService) {
  }


/***************************** EDIT  **********************/


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Give a reference to your element
<input #myName>
@ViewChild('myName') input; 
ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(this.input.nativeElement.value);
}
```

Here we are giving a local reference (#myname) to our input DOM element so that we can access it in ts file. The ViewChild decorator is available in package @Angular/core. It takes a class type or a reference name string. Here we are giving reference name string for variable input. ngAfterViewInit()  is a life cycle hook in Angular which is invoked after view is initialized. In this lifecycle hook we will be able to access input element (since it has been initialized) and all of its properties.

Comment: Could you give more clarification and explanation to make this a higher quality answer?

Comment: I have edited my answer for better explanation. Please check.